# How to get active socket connection count in Play Framework?

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I want to get traffic / connection count in Play framework for test and monitoring.

Is there real time server status monitor on the Play framework?

Answer (score 1):

I think New relic has a beautiful way of doing this:

http://newrelic.com/application-monitoring

Comment: hm,OK. I should get current establish counts in outside of Play! application. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Play is based on Jboss Netty, so you need to look on how to check number of connections in Netty.